# Clarification on the proof of $ ab^{-1}\in H \implies Ha=Hb $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm reading Robert Ash's [*Basic Abstract Algebra.*](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Er-ash/Algebra.html) I am trying to prove that:

> Given cosets $Ha,Hb$, show:
>
> $ ab^{-1}\in H  \implies Ha=Hb $

I've tried the following:

> 1. Proved $a\in H \implies Ha=H $
> 2. $Hab^{-1}=H$
> 3. $Hab^{-1}b=Hb$
> 4. $Ha=Hb$

Which I'm not sure if is valid, the multiplication by $b$ sounds suspicious to me because I know $1,ab^{-1},ba^{-1}\in H$ because $H$ is a group, but I don't know if this guarantees $a,b\in H$. The answer given by the book is the following:

> If $ab^{-1}=h\in H$, then $Ha=Hhb=Hb$.

I am in doubt at to what is happening here. I guess he is saying the following:

$$Ha\stackrel{a=hb}{=}Hhb = (Hh)b \stackrel{Ha=H}{=} Hb $$

This makes sense to me, but I guess 1. Isn't proved in the book.

Comment: Does "the book" prove that cosets are either equal or disjoint?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown No, but I've seen that in a companion book im reading along with it.  I guess he expects me to know some things because there are things which are demonstrated in this companion book that aren't demonstrated in the main book.

Answer (score 2):

It's all easier than that.  Let $ha$ be an arbitrary element of $Ha$.  Note that $ha=hab^{-1}b =(hab^{-1})b$ (parenthetical separation for emphasis).  But $hab^{-1} \in H$ since both $h, ab^{-1} \in H$ and $H$ is a subgroup, so this writes $ha$ as an element of $Hb$.  Hence $Ha \subseteq Hb$ and a symmetric argument gets $Hb \subseteq Ha$.

In the author's argument, he uses the fact that $H(hb)=Hb$ when $h \in H$, thereby "absorbing" the $h$ into the subgroup $H$.  This is indeed true no matter what $b$ is and is easy to prove.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused: Why $hab^{-1}\in H$? I know that $h \in H$ and it could be that $a \notin H$.

Comment: @BillyRubina $ab^{-1}\in H$.

Comment: @BillyRubina edited to clarify